# gcc compilation in aarch64 architecture

Tags: c, gcc

I'm running Ubuntu 16.04.2 in a quad-core ARM Cortex-A53 platform with an architecture aarch64. I've implemented an application in C that is compiled with gcc. I was expecting that this app was for 64 bit, but when I run "file MyApp" I obtain:

"MyApp: ELF 32-bit LSB executable, ARM, EABI5 version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, interpreter /lib/ld-linux-armhf.so.3, for GNU/Linux 3.2.0, BuildID[sha1]=2a83542bc6e3cd46b7c87b7f365c4f1081f7fcc9, not stripped"

Is this an expected result or am I missing something? I would need to have a 64-bit app.

Comment: Can you provide the exact gcc command you used for compilation? You might need to specify 64bit explicitly.

Comment: Is this: "gcc -o ../MyApp MyApp.c -I/usr/local/include -L/usr/local/lib -lwebsockets -l json-c -lm -g3 -Wall"

Comment: What does `gcc -v` say for 'Target:'? Does `-m64` help? (that might just be x86_64 only though)

Comment: --target=arm-linux-gnueabihf.
-m64 is not recognized